# Erro: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

estou tendo um problema na exibição da minha lista de recados, está dando esse erro:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /###/###/###/view/list.php on line 11
```

No arquivo está assim:

```
<div class="container marketing">

    <?php foreach ($listaRecados as $r): ?>
      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading"><?php echo $r->titulo; ?></span></h2>
          <p class="lead"><?php echo $r->texto; ?></p>
          <a href="recado.php?action=excluir&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
          <a href="recado.php?action=curtir&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a> <?php echo $r->likes; ?> - <?php echo $r->autor; ?>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

A linha 12 é essa: `<?php foreach ($listaRecados as $r): ?>`

Comment: `$listaRecado` não é um array, verifique seu valor.

Comment: coloca um print_r($listaRecados); e observa o retorno, como o comentário a cima $listaRecados não é um array

Comment: Na verdade ele está puxando o $listaRecado do recado.php, eu sou muito iniciante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verifique sé a Variavel "$listaRecados" que está chamando e exatamente uma Array, utilize a empty() para fazer essa verificação.

```
 if(!empty($listaRecados)): foreach($listaRecados as $r): endforeach; else: echo "Array Vazio" endif;
```